# Excel Formula to look up a value in another table, but bring through ALL results

Tags: excel

I have set up data consolidation so the user can select from a list of dates. When the user changes the date, I want a formula (preferably a formula rather than VBA), if one exists, to look up the date in the table contained on the next page and bring through information based on this data.

I know that vlookups can look up on the table obviously with something like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(dateCell, table, colIndex, False)
```

But this seems to only bring through the first result- is there any way I can set this up so that after the first result has been brought through, I can bring through the second, third, fourth, etc. There will be multiple occurrences of each date so there will be multiple values that I want to bring through- one on each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the example:
In A1:A5 values A,B,C,A,D
In B1:B5 values 3,5,6,8,9

Looking for value A in A1:A5 and get all the corresponding matches in B1:B5

Write this array formula in D1

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$5;SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$5="A";ROW($A$1:$A$5);"");ROWS($D$1:D1)))
```

You get the first value (3), copy the formula down and you get all the others

Dont forget to Ctrl Shift Enter to enter the formula

Comment: I had to change the semi-colons to commas for it to work but spot on otherwise. Cheers

Comment: sorry my Excel field separator is the ";"... :)

Answer (score 0):

Use **AutoFilter** to select the desired date, then copy all the visible rows to your destination.